# How to use query results in url regex in Django

Tags: regex, django, django-urls, python-import

I want to use a database query to generate my URL configuration. Something like:

```
states = State.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

And then a regex like:

```
(r'^state/(?P<state>' + '|'.join(states) + ')/$'
```

The idea is that I can have URLs like:

```
/state/ca/
/state/az/
```

Etc.

The problem is that when I do `syncdb`, the query above fails, throwing a `DatabaseError`.

Is there a good way to do this? I've tried the obvious change, which would be:

```
try:
    states = State.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
except DatabaseError:
    # First sync, use dummy data
    states = []
```

But this doesn't work because the exception is thrown at the regex, not at the query definition.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to constrain this in the URL pattern itself? Much better to accept all two-letter codes, and check in the view.

```
(r'^state/(?P<state_code>\w{2})/$'

def view_state(request, state_code):
    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_code)
```

Comment: Good call. No particularly good reason to do it there. Sometimes I just get blind in my approach. Thanks.